# CSS: align ul li items to center (with margin) without flex model

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have such code:

```
<ul class="tiles">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
ul.tiles{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #cecece;
    padding: 0;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #8ac249;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

and it look so:

[image]

is it real to change it to such model (without flex box):

[image]

and how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add `text-align:center` to your `ul`. Text-align center can be useful for a number of situations and can be used for more than just text. It can be used on any inline or inline-block elements and can achieve some neat little things like this.

```css
ul.tiles{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #cecece;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #8ac249;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tiles">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you saying your li's are floated so this won't work? If so, do they need to be floated?

Comment: Yeah, it won't work with floating. I'm not sure there's a way when they're floated? I'm guessing you have a reason to float them, can I ask what it is?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/34g77nsa/ - so it is broken (if i add float all is ok, but is wrong positioned)

Comment: did you saw my fiddler?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Yes, add `vertical-align:top` to your `li` tags. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/andyfurniss/0jcjhj11/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.tiles{
    width: 220px;
    height: 200px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #cecece;
    padding: 0;`enter code here`
    text-align:center;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #8ac249;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

---

> put text-align:center; in ul.tiles